# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.example.xxxxxxxx.models.User.getFullName()' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android

first of all Happy new year to everyone. I am new to Android and Firebase and have a problem in passing data from one Activity (RegisterActivity) to another (MenuActivity) that contains the DrawerLayout. How can I fix my error? I've tried several solutions but none of them work. This is the error:

RegisterActivity.java

```
 @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                if(task.isSuccessful()) {
                    Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "User successful created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Intent registrationIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MenuActivity.class);
                    Bundle data = new Bundle();
                    data.putString("EMAIL", email);
                    registrationIntent.putExtras(data);
                    startActivity(registrationIntent);
                    finish();
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Error! " +
                            task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
```

MenuActivity.java

```
private DrawerLayout drawer;
    private ImageView imageProfile;
    private TextView userName;
    private TextView email;
    private User user;
    private String identification;
    private NavigationView navigationView;

        @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);

        Intent intentReceived = getIntent();
        Bundle data = intentReceived.getExtras();
        if(data != null){
            identification = data.getString("EMAIL");
        }
        else{
            identification = "";
        }

        View navHeaderView = ((NavigationView)findViewById(R.id.nav_view)).getHeaderView(0);

        ((TextView) navHeaderView.findViewById(R.id.userName)).setText(user.getUserName());
        ((TextView) navHeaderView.findViewById(R.id.userEmail)).setText(user.getEmail());

        Bitmap bitmapsinfoto = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.profile);
        RoundedBitmapDrawable roundedBitmapDrawablesinfoto = RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory.create(getResources(), bitmapsinfoto);
        roundedBitmapDrawablesinfoto.setCircular(true);

        ((ImageView) navHeaderView.findViewById(R.id.imageProfile)).setImageDrawable(roundedBitmapDrawablesinfoto);

        if(user.getBytes()!=null) {
            byte[] foodImage = user.getBytes();
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(foodImage, 0, foodImage.length);

            ((ImageView) navHeaderView.findViewById(R.id.imageProfile)).setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            Bitmap bitmap2 = ((BitmapDrawable)((ImageView) navHeaderView.findViewById(R.id.imageProfile)).getDrawable()).getBitmap();
            RoundedBitmapDrawable roundedBitmapDrawable = RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory.create(getResources(), bitmap2);
            roundedBitmapDrawable.setCircular(true);

            ((ImageView) navHeaderView.findViewById(R.id.imageProfile)).setImageDrawable(roundedBitmapDrawable);
        }

        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar,
                R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);

        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        if(savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                    new MenuFragment()).commit();
            navigationView.setCheckedItem(R.id.nav_menu);
        }
```

User.java

```
public class User {

    private byte[] bytes;
    private String id, email, password, userName;
    private boolean active;

    public byte[] getBytes() {
        return bytes;
    }

    public void setBytes(byte[] bytes) {
        this.bytes = bytes;
    }

    public User() {  }

    public User(boolean active) {
        this.active = active;
    }

    public User(String id, String email, String password, String userName) {
        this.id = id;
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public User(String id, String email, String password, byte[] bytes, String userName) {
        this.bytes = bytes;
        this.id = id;
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public boolean isActive() {
        return active;
    }

    public void setActive(boolean active) {
        this.active = active;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public void setPassword(String pass) {
        this.password = pass;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance everyone for the answer.

Comment: Upload your code. Logs alone cannot help. You are getting an  NullPointerException. Might be String passed is null.

Comment: yes, I added the code that generates the error

Comment: Have you added complete code of onCreate of MenuActivity.java . If not so, plz upload complete code. The code you added above seems to be correct.

Comment: Now i added the whole code of onCreate of MenuActivity.java @Mrudul Tora

Answer (score 1):

From your code of MenuActivity.java it is somewhat clear that you haven't instantiated the object of **User** class. *For ex,*

```
((TextView) navHeaderView.findViewById(R.id.userName)).setText(user.getUserName());
((TextView) navHeaderView.findViewById(R.id.userEmail)).setText(user.getEmail());
```

In the above two lines you have used `user.getUserName()` but you haven't instantiated it before like `User user=new User()` or anything as you have overloaded the constructor.

**Edit:** Yours is not showing name and email in drawer because the `user.getUserName()` and `user.getEmail()` may be empty.
Try passing the values in the constructor with all the required arguments.

Comment: Great bro it seems to work, but now it doesn't show username and email in Drawer, how is it possible? @Mrudul Tora

Comment: Yes, surely they are empty as they are not passed by the RegisterActivity, but I don't understand why.

Comment: @FrancescoBottiglia See that will depend on the constructor you have used. If you have used the constructor User(String id, String email, String password, String userName) then it should work properly.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll try this solution.